# Mutating the same data in multiple 'static closures

Tags: rust

Given a library (for instance a GUI library) that uses callbacks to communicate events to the library user, how would I proceed to have proper mutability in the program? For instance:

```
// so I have this `obj` I want to modify when the user clicks buttons
// in the GUI

let same_action = move |_| {
  // modify obj in several ways, e.g. obj.text = "Modified"
  obj.text = "Modified";
}
// --> I had to move `obj` above since `on_click` has a `'static`
// constraint for `F` but that's not really a thing I want to do,
// I want to keep control of `obj` in the outer scope!!!

// --> error because `same_action` does not implement `Fn` since it
// mutates the moved `obj` in it
button1.on_click(same_action);
// --> if the above worked, here we'd have a error because `button1`
// has moved `same_action`
button2.on_click(same_action);
// --> assuming all of the above worked, we'd have a error here about
// unable to use `obj` because it has been moved to same_action
button3.on_click(move |_| obj.text = "Another modifier");

// the library now process the gui and call the callbacks in a loop
// until exit
gui_run();

// --> ..., error cannot use `obj` because it has been moved by
// `same_action`
println!("Final value: {}", obj.text);
```

See the comments with `// -->` for the critical points of this question.

This seems like a pretty common problem to worry on event-driven APIs in Rust.
How'd one get around it?

Comment: What kind of protection against concurrent mutation do you have? What do other event-driven APIs do to deal with races caused by concurrent mutation?

Comment: @Shepmaster Concurrency is disallowed, i.e. it's guaranted the callbacks will be called in the same thread as `gui_run`. I think it doesn't even allow using the API from another thread other than the main one.

Comment: Concurrency isn't even important. Two aliasing `&mut`s (or even just one `&mut` and a `&`)  within one thread is enough to get you into hot water, for example around iterator invalidation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to share mutable data, you need some container that make sure that the aliasing rules are being followed, most likely one from [`std::cell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/). For `Copy` data this is `Cell`, for other types there's `RefCell`. Then the closures can use either:

- `Cell<TheObject>`/`Cell<TheObject>`, or
- `TheObject` where some fields are `Cell`s and `RefCell`s.

Which is better depends on how granular you want the mutability to be and whether this is a common need for all users of `TheObject` or just for this particular closure. In the second case, you need to alter the definition of `TheObject`, in the first you'd do something like this:

```
let obj = RefCell::new(obj);

let same_action = move |_| {
  obj.borrow_mut().text = "Modified";
}
```

If you furthermore can't have borrows in the closure's captured values, for example because of a `'static` bound, you can put the `RefCell` into an `Rc`.

Also, you can't pass `same_action` to two buttons because closures can't be copied or cloned. In general this can't be done, because they might close over things that can't be copied or cloned. When possible, it may be allowed in the future, for now you can work around it with a macro, a function (that would have to box the closure), or by simply writing the closure twice if it's simple.

Comment: Good point about the cells type, but the issues pointed in the code comments are is still up as the `RefCell` `obj` has been moved into `same_action` (cannot take it as `&` because static lifetime in the constraint `F: Fn(...) + 'static`), therefore it cannot be used in the outer scope neither in `button3` callback. Plus a alternative to the fact `same_action` not being able to be used twice (at `button1` and `button2`) is welcome in the answer.

Comment: @thelink2012 I think I addressed that now.

Comment: Oh, `Rc<RefCell<T>>`, good, that made it work, thanks! Is there some sugar to the `let x = rc.clone()` I have to do before each closure move? And, not that I'm on a performance critical system but just out of curiosity since the `Rc<RefCell<T>>` seems to be a common pattern in Rust and `Rc` performing dynamic allocation wouldn't this piece of dynamic allocation be a bad thing considering Rust intends to be used in performance critical systems?

Comment: @thelink2012 `Rc<RefCell<_>>` (or plain `Rc<_>`) is/should be only used when it's necessary. And if it's necessary, well... you probably can't avoid the allocation anyway, or not easily. Rust *allows* you to avoid allocations and other expensive things, you still have the responsibility to decide if it's worth it.