# How can I construct a container from within a closure with a 'static bound?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I'm using the [libpulse_binding](https://docs.rs/libpulse-binding/2.5.0/libpulse_binding/index.html) library, and I'm trying to obtain a sequence of [`SinkInputInfo`](https://docs.rs/libpulse-binding/2.5.0/libpulse_binding/context/introspect/struct.SinkInputInfo.html)s from the [`get_sink_input_info_list`](https://docs.rs/libpulse-binding/2.5.0/libpulse_binding/context/introspect/struct.Introspector.html#method.get_sink_input_info_list) function:

```
pub fn get_sink_input_info_list<F>(
    &self,
    callback: F,
) -> Operation<dyn FnMut(ListResult<&SinkInputInfo>)>
where
    F: FnMut(ListResult<&SinkInputInfo>) + 'static,
```

The function takes a callback and calls it once for each `SinkInputInfo` it produces. I'm trying to collect all those `SinkInputInfo`s into a single list so I can get a clearer view of the state of the world. Irritatingly, `SinkInputInfo` doesn't implement `Copy` or `Clone`, so I made a custom struct and implemented `From` to get the useful information out of the `SinkInputInfo`:

```
struct StreamInfo {
    readable_name: String,
    binary_name: String,
    pid: String,
}

impl From<&pulse::context::introspect::SinkInputInfo<'_>> for StreamInfo {
    fn from(info: &pulse::context::introspect::SinkInputInfo) -> Self {
        let name = info.proplist.gets("application.name").unwrap();
        let binary = info.proplist.gets("application.process.binary").unwrap();
        let pid = info.proplist.gets("application.process.id").unwrap();
        StreamInfo {
            readable_name: name,
            binary_name: binary,
            pid: pid,
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I have the following code:

```
let mut sink_infos: Vec<StreamInfo> = Vec::new();
let op = introspector.get_sink_input_info_list(|result| match result {
    pulse::callbacks::ListResult::Item(info) => sink_infos.push(info.into()),
    pulse::callbacks::ListResult::End => {},
    pulse::callbacks::ListResult::Error => panic!("Error getting sink input info"),
});
```

but it doesn't compile:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `sink_infos`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/bin/play-pause.rs:49:52
   |
49 |     let op = introspector.get_sink_input_info_list(|result| match result {
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `sink_infos`
50 |         pulse::callbacks::ListResult::Item(info) => sink_infos.push(info.into()),
   |                                                     ---------- `sink_infos` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
  --> src/bin/play-pause.rs:49:14
   |
49 |       let op = introspector.get_sink_input_info_list(|result| match result {
   |  ______________^
50 | |         pulse::callbacks::ListResult::Item(info) => sink_infos.push(info.into()),
51 | |         pulse::callbacks::ListResult::End => {},
52 | |         pulse::callbacks::ListResult::Error => panic!("Error getting sink input info"),
53 | |     });
   | |______^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `sink_infos` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
49 |     let op = introspector.get_sink_input_info_list(move |result| match result {
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

tldr: the closure has to have the `'static` lifetime because libpulse_binding says so (presumably because it gets handed to the PulseAudio C API, which can then do whatever it likes with it), but `sink_infos` is not `'static`, and the closure has to borrow `sink_infos` in order to append to it, which makes the closure not `'static`, IIUC.

How can I make a `Vec` (or any container, I'm not fussy) of `SinkInputInfo`s given a `'static` closure that gets called repeatedly with a `&SinkInputInfo`?

Comment: Do you agree this is a duplicate of [Mutating the same data in multiple 'static closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30153973/155423)?

Comment: @Shepmaster That looks like fundamentally the same question, yes – I can only assume I wasn't searching for the right things to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you're running into [Rust's borrowing rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html):

> Given an object `T`, it is only possible to have one of the following:
>
> - Having several immutable references (`&T`) to the object (also known as **aliasing**).
> - Having one mutable reference (`&mut T`) to the object (also known as **mutability**).

You are trying to keep a reference `&Vec` to your Vec (so you can use it later) whilst simultaneously trying to add things to it in a closure (i.e. an `&mut Vec`). Rust doesn't know that you won't try to use the `&Vec` while the closure is using the `&mut Vec`, so it doesn't let you create a `&mut Vec` in the closure while there's still a `&Vec` hanging around outside the closure.

The next best thing you can do is to use an [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html). This will allow you to sidestep the compiler's borrow-checking and instead defer it to runtime. However: this means that if you try to violate the borrowing rules while your program is running, it will panic instead of being a compile-time error!

For the most part, you can treat the `Rc<Vec<_>>` the same as a normal `Vec`, since `Rc` implements `Deref`.

Since you also want to be able to mutate the `Vec` in order to add things to it, you also need to put it in a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html). This will put a lock around the `Vec`, making sure that you only have one `&mut Vec` available at once, and that if you have an `&Vec`, you can't have a `&mut Vec` (again, if you try to violate the rules, your program will panic). You can use the `.borrow()` and `.borrow_mut()` methods on `RefCell` to get shared and mutable references to the Vec (there are also `try_*` variants of these methods, if you can do something sensible if a borrow is not possible).

If you didn't use a `RefCell`, you would only be able to obtain immutable/shared references (`&Vec`) from the `Rc` (unless you only had one `Rc`, but then you wouldn't need an `Rc`!)

Try something like the following:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

let sink_infos: Rc<RefCell<Vec<StreamInfo>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));
let sink_infos2 = sink_infos.clone(); // Create a new Rc which points to the same data.
let op = introspector.get_sink_input_info_list(move |result| match result {
    pulse::callbacks::ListResult::Item(info) => sink_infos2.borrow_mut().push(info.into()),
    pulse::callbacks::ListResult::End => {},
    pulse::callbacks::ListResult::Error => panic!("Error getting sink input info"),
});
```